# jstree don't add new node

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I've just copied the demo code from the site http://www.jstree.com/ of jstree and tried to add the option of new node. There is no error but it don't add new node.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>jsTree test</title>
     <!-- 2 load the theme CSS file -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/themes/default/style.min.css" />
     </head>
     <body>
     <!-- 3 setup a container element -->
     <div id="jstree">
     <!-- in this example the tree is populated from inline HTML -->
     <ul>
     <li>Root node 1
     <ul>
     <li id="child_node_1">Child node 1</li>
     <li>Child node 2</li>
     </ul>
     </li>
     <li>Root node 2</li>
     </ul>
     </div>
     <button>demo button</button>

     <!-- 4 include the jQuery library -->
     <script src="dist/libs/jquery.js"></script>
     <!-- 5 include the minified jstree source -->
     <script src="dist/jstree.min.js"></script>
     <script>
     $(function () {
     // 6 create an instance when the DOM is ready
     $('#jstree').jstree();
     // 7 bind to events triggered on the tree
     $('#jstree').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
     console.log(data.selected);
     });
     // 8 interact with the tree - either way is OK
     $('button').on('click', function () {
     $('#jstree').jstree(true).select_node('child_node_1');
     //$('#jstree').jstree().create_node(null,'AAA','last'); first option
     //$("#jstree").jstree("create_node", $("j1_3"), "after", { "data": "Hello"); 
     $('#jstree').jstree('select_node', 'child_node_1');
     $.jstree.reference('#jstree').select_node('child_node_1');
     });
     });
     </script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Look at remarked lines. No error but don't add rhe new node. Does somebody have any idea?

Comment: Have you tried using "#" for the parent parameter? '$('#jstree').jstree().create_node("#","AAA","last");'

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$('#jstree').jstree("create_node", "parent_id", function(e,data){
         console.log('hi', data);
    });
```